# Select Rows with a certain value present

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have created a correlation matrix using the Pandas method `df.corr()`. I need to select the rows in which I have even one value greater than 0.7. How do I achieve this?

P.S.: There are over 60 columns in my dataset, hence I need to vectorize this. Also it is important to understand that there is a value 1.0 in every row (every column is perfectly correlated with itself). Hence I only need to choose rows which have values greater than 0.7 apart from that 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Boolean masking and the `loc` accessor:

```
# Since the maximum value is 1, this should also work:
df.loc[((df>0.7) & (df<1)).any(1)]
# OR
df.loc[df.replace(1, float('NaN')).gt(0.7).any(1)]
```

Comment: Little issue with this that in a correlation matrix there will always be a value = 1(Cause every element is perfectly correlated with itself). So every row will be selected.

Comment: @sinha-shaurya so you can ignore that row

Comment: Every row has 1.0 as a value. Cause a correlation matrix gives a correlation between every  pair of columns, including itself

Comment: @sinha-shaurya updated answer...kindly have a look

Comment: @jezrael sir I think 1st would also work since the max value is 1

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` to avoid matching all rows with `1`, and compare for greater than `0.7` if at least one row:

```
df[df.replace(1,0).gt(0.7).any(axis=1)]
```

compare

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use `gt`:

```
print(df[df.gt(0.7).any(axis=1)])
```